# IE9 and SVG issues and SVGeezy

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-9

Ok - I have tried multiple things and IE9 just won't display SVG correctly. I have given up. Is there any way to force the use of SVGeezy if IE9 is detected or to force fallback to png if IE9 is detected? I would really appreciate someone sharing the code to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Remove the width, height and aspect ratio from the svg file and add viewbox parameters. It finally works in IE9+, Firefox and Chrome.